# PHP empty function - Associative Array

Tags: php

Can anyone explain why this is returns non-empty?

```
<?php

$attributes=array("description"=>"","quantity"=>"","price"=>"","discount"=>"");

if(empty($attributes))
   echo 'empty';
else
    echo 'non empty';
exit;

?>
```

Comment: It is because the array element has keys in it although it has no values in it so it is being considered as non-empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [manual documentation for `empty()`](http://php.net/empty):

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. **A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.** empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

In this case, the variable `$attributes` exists and it's not equal to FALSE. So `empty()` will return boolean `FALSE`.

**To check if each one of them is empty and echo a message:**

```
foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        echo "'$key' is empty\n";
    }
}
```

**To check if *all* the array values are empty:**

```
if(!array_filter($attributes)) {
    echo 'All values are empty';
}
```

**To check if *any* of the array values are empty:**

```
if (array_search('', $attributes) !== FALSE) {
    echo 'One of the values in the array is empty';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have an array of empty strings, which is not an empty array.

Comment: okay. Thanks. But What is the better way to check if the above array is empty or not?